How to remove image distortion in flutter
My requirement is to render images without distortion(The image is not drawn continuously, for example in the mobile image in the character m there are several gaps, I need to render without any break). I will be receiving base64-encoded images from different platforms, such as web applications and mobile applications, and need to render these images in my mobile application. The images should have a minimum width and height of 58 and 14, respectively. When I render the base64 image obtained from the web app, there is no distortion. However, when I render the image using data received from the mobile application, the images get distorted. I have attached a sample where the web image is stored in the webData variable and the mobile image is stored in the mobData variable. I have rendered the image using Image.memory. Despite trying several widgets, I have not been able to achieve my expectation. To replicate the image distortion, render the images in the mobile application, then take a screenshot and zoom in. Attached are images for this case.


But when I increase the size like 150*50 for mob data, the distortion is not available, so I suspect, am doing something wrong while rendering those images. The data can be found here
Simple code snippet can be found below
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_signaturepad/signaturepad.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const SignaturePadApp());
}

///Renders the SignaturePad widget.
class SignaturePadApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const SignaturePadApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: 'SfSignaturePad Demo',
      home: _MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class _MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const _MyHomePage();

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<_MyHomePage> {
  final GlobalKey<SfSignaturePadState> signatureGlobalKey = GlobalKey();

  String value = 'web';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
          body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Container(
                width: 487,
                height: 158,
                decoration:
                    BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey)),
                child: Center(
                  child: Image.memory(
                    base64Decode(value == 'web' ? webData : mobData),
                    isAntiAlias: true,
                    height: 14,
                    width: 58,
                    filterQuality: FilterQuality.high,
                  ),
                )),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                TextButton(
                  child: Text('Render Web Image'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      value = 'web';
                    });
                  },
                ),
                TextButton(
                  child: Text('Render Mobile Image'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      value = 'mob';
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      )),
    );
  }
}

String webData = '';

String mobData =  '';


I don't get your problem: What exactly do you mean with "distortion"? That you see artifacts in the image? That the width and height are not scaled proportional?

The image is not drawn continuously, for example in the mobile image in the character m there are several gaps, I need to render without any break

so you are not transferring the final bitmaps but "drawing instructions"?
